# Mongoose rename collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make [db.collection.renameCollection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.renameCollection/) with mongoose, but i can't find that function anywhere. Did they miss to add it or i am looking at wrong place?
As quick example of what i am doing is:

```
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('localhost',"dbname");
var Collection = conn.model(collectionName, Schema, collectionName);
console.log(typeof Collection.renameCollection);
```

Which show undefined.

```
var con = mongoose.createConnection('localhost',"dbname");
con.once('open', function() {
    console.log(typeof con.db[obj.name]);
});
```

This give also undefined.

Comment: format should be `db.collectionName.renameCollection("NewCollectionName")` You are not passing the new collection name. Even tough its in the Collection variable you need to pass the correct parameter if you expect the function to work

Comment: I will edit post and add answer to your comment in few minutes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an example that will perform a rename operation using Mongoose.

```
const mongoose   = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test').then(() => {
  console.log('connected');

  // Access the underlying database object provided by the MongoDB driver.
  let db = mongoose.connection.db;

  // Rename the `test` collection to `foobar`
  return db.collection('test').rename('foobar');
}).then(() => {
  console.log('rename successful');
}).catch(e => {
  console.log('rename failed:', e.message);
}).then(() => {
  console.log('disconnecting');
  mongoose.disconnect();
});
```

As you can see, the MongoDB driver exposes the `renameCollection()` method as `rename()`, which is documented here: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#rename

Comment: this looks to work, but i need to test it, i will reply here in 1h.

Comment: `.rename('test')` did the trick, i was looking for collectionRename.