# How to rename a collection without loosing data of collection in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using Mongoose in my NodeJs project. I want to rename my collection from `OldCollectionName` to `NewCollectionName`.

I tried following:

`Mongoose.connection.collection('OldCollectionName').rename('NewCollectionName');`

But this is making my collection empty. Can someone suggest how can I change the collection name without loosing my collection data? I need all the data from `OldCollectionName` in `NewCollectionName` as well.

I have following schema for my model

```
const Mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongooseSequence  = require('mongoose-sequence');
const Schema = Mongoose.Schema;
var collectionSchema = new Schema({
    collectionIdAutoIncrement: { type: Number,unique: true,index:true,sparse:true},
    fieldName: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    otherCollectionId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "OtherCollection",
    },
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated: { type: Date},
});

collectionSchema.plugin(mongooseSequence, { inc_field: 'collectionIdAutoIncrement' });
var oldCollection = Mongoose.model('OldCollectionName', collectionSchema);
```

Comment: try this `mongoose.connection.db.collection('OldCollectionName').rename('NewCollectionName');`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose rename collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43391592/mongoose-rename-collection)